# JSP: Format date within a <form:input> field?

Tags: jsp, date

I have a JSP form element that looks like:

```
<form:input path="foo" id="bar" value="${myObject.myDate}" class="fizz buzz bang"/>
```

and I want to format this date so that it initially appears like: yyyy/mm/dd

I know I can format a date in JSP easily like this:

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${blah.bla}" pattern="MM-dd-yyyy" />
```

but how can I combine the two?

When I do:

```
 <form:input path="foo" id="bar" value=" <fmt:formatDate value="${myObject.myDate}" pattern="MM-dd-yyyy" /> " class="fizz buzz bang"/>
```

I get exceptions on the line like:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unterminated form:input tag
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot directly use `<fmt:formatDate>` inside the form input tag. You can format it and assign the variable to value of form input.

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${blah.bla}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" var="myDate" />
<form:input path="foo" id="bar" value="${myDate} />
```

Hope this helps.

- Source

  1. [Spring mvc date format with form:input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18163404/spring-mvc-date-format-with-forminput)
  2. [How to make fmt:formatDate work for form:input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736150/how-to-make-fmtformatdate-work-for-forminput)

Comment: Ah... so it seems the actual problem here was me not knowing basic JSP syntax! Thanks for your help!